# Polynomial roots or discriminant

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, matrices

I was wondering if it is possible to find the roots of the following polynomial
$$
P(x)=x^n+ax^m+b
$$
or at least can I get the discriminant of it, which is the determinant of the Sylvester matrix associated to $P(x)$ and $P'(x)$.

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the resultant of a pair of polynomials?

Comment: I know just the basics about it.
I tried to calculate the determinant, but I couldn't get a recurrence relation ...

Comment: For your first question $n=5$, $m=1$, $a=-1$, $b=1$, doesn't have roots written in radicals. "Find" is going to be hard type of "find".

Comment: Ok that's true. Actually in my case $a<0$ and $b>0$ so it doesn't help. This is why I finally decided to try to get at least the discriminant, which might be possible because the matrix is not very complicated ...

Comment: Because $a<0$, by a redefinition of $x$, we can always rewrite the roots in the form
$$y^n-y^m+\alpha=0$$
Would it be simpler for the discriminant?

Comment: I got part of the idea. The roots $\{a_i\}$ of $P'(x)$ are easy to get, hence we have a theorem which says that the resultant is proportional to $\prod_i P(a_i)$. I was not yet able to simplify that product ...

Answer (score 1):

With the notations of ziu. Here $n>m$. Let $\lambda=(m/n)^{\dfrac{1}{n-m}}$ and $\omega=exp(2i\pi k/(n-m))$. The roots of $P'$ are $0$ ($m-1$ times) and the $(\lambda\omega^k)$. Such a root is a multiple one iff $\alpha+\omega^{kn}\lambda^n-\omega^{km}\lambda^m=0$. Finally, up to a multiplicative factor, $discrim(P)=\alpha^{m-1}Q(\alpha)$ where $Q(\alpha)=\Pi_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha+\omega^{kn}\lambda^n-\omega^{km}\lambda^m)=\Pi_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha+\omega^{km}(\lambda^n-\lambda^m))$.